# WordPress Admin Area - Add class to body of page edit screen

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I used wp-types toolset to create a custom post type and a post relationship to pages; there is now a Post Relationships section at the bottom of every page edit screen. The problem is, I would only like this section to show up on a couple of pages.

Is there something I can add to functions.php (or another alternative) to hide this section from all page edit screens expect for those particular ones.

The section div id that I want to hide is #wpcf-post-relationship and the data post id of the pages that I would like it to be visible are 143 and 23.

Comment: Have you tried adding an array of id's in the screen parameter for the add_meta_box function? something like array(143, 43)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-- (*update*) --

> As `admin_init` is triggered before any other hook when a user access
>   the admin area, we finally use instead `admin_head` because action is
>   just triggered inside the `<head>` of the admin page *(thanks to [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2190350/john))*.

The easy way is to use a simple CSS rule with the 'admin_head' hook, to do it, like this:

1) create a css file named `hide_some_field.css` and put it into your active child theme folder, with this code:

```css
#wpcf-post-relationship {
    display:none;
}
```

2) Add this code in your active child theme functions.php file:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'ts_hiding_some_fields');
function ts_hiding_some_fields(){
    // your 2 pages in this array
    $arr = array(23, 143);
    if(get_post_type() == 'page' && !in_array(get_the_ID(), $arr))
    {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'hide_some_field', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/hide_some_field.css');
    }
}
```

If you use a **theme** instead, change:
`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` by `get_template_directory_uri()`.

Another similar alternative *(without an external CSS file)* is:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'ts_hiding_some_fields');
function ts_hiding_some_fields(){
    // your 2 pages in this array
    $arr = array(23, 143);
    if(get_post_type() == 'page' && !in_array(get_the_ID(), $arr))
    {
        echo '<style type="text/css">
        #wpcf-post-relationship {display: none;}
        </style>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome!! I had to change admin_init to admin_head but otherwise the code was spot on. Thanks, brother!

Comment: Nice, it worked for you! I will update the code here with `admin_head` instead off `admin_init`  :)